# Python class enforce type hinting

Tags: python, python-typing

So I need to enforce the type of a class variable, but more importantly, I need to enforce a list with its types. So if I have some code which looks like this:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, value: list[int]):
        self.value = value
```

Btw I'm using python version 3.9.4

So essentially my question is, how can I make sure that value is a list of integers.

Thanks in advance

- Zac

Comment: Please be aware that type *hints* are only meant for that – hints. While checking them statically (e.g. via mypy) can be practically useful, runtime checking has excessive cost in all but the most trivial cases. Are you fine with just verifying the program statically, or do you need runtime verification? What kind of types do you need to check, and what type system do you assume? For example, do you need to check only concrete types or also abstract types and generic types? Do you need to respect variance?

Comment: So I'm building a pypi module so I need runtime checks to make sure that no errors are thrown whilst giving the user an error which they can understand without having to go into the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to check the instances type directly and raise error if they're not in the types you want.

```py
class foo:
    def __init__(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, list) or not all(isinstance(x, int) for x in value):
            raise TypeError("value should be a list of integers")
            
        self.value = value
```

Comment: this is a simple fix. All I have to do is add a else statement to from the first if and then put the second if statement inside of the else

Comment: Note that the type hint ``list[int]`` is *invariant* – it would not allow for ``int`` subclasses. This corresponds to the check ``type(x) is int`` instead of ``isinstance(x, int)``.

Comment: @Zachary the code edited again. `not any` now should change to `not all`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to type checking (which is only enforced by linters) you could `assert`

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, value: list[int]):
        assert isinstance(value, list) and all(isinstance(i, int) for i in value)
        self.value = value

>>> foo([1,2,3])  # good
<__main__.foo object at 0x000001EB492A5940>

>>> foo('abc')  # bad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    foo('abc')
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 3, in __init__
    assert isinstance(value, list) and all(isinstance(i, int) for i in value)
AssertionError

>>> foo([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])  # bad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    foo([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 3, in __init__
    assert isinstance(value, list) and all(isinstance(i, int) for i in value)
AssertionError
```

In addition to a simple assertion, you could also `raise` and perhaps implement a custom exception for callers to handle these.