# How to enforce composed type hints in python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Is there a way to enforce composed type hints in python? I am looking to get the following behaviour:

```
import type_enforced

@type_enforced.Enforcer
def my_fn(a: list[int]) -> None:
    pass

my_fn(a=[1, 2])   # This should work
my_fn(a=[1, '2']) # This should raise an exception
```

Note that the issue lies in `list[int]`. When I use just `def my_fn(a: list) -> None:`, the code runs without any error.

I have seen the related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67080686/python-class-enforce-type-hinting) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74184800/python-enforce-type-hints), but they did not bring me closer.

Comment: You might have better luck researching this by properly calling it a parameterized type, rather than "composed" (which sounds like it should mean, for example, a `Union`). Anyway, this is going to depend on the library you're using; please start by **reading the documentation**. It seems like you mean [this project](https://pypi.org/project/type-enforced/); that's clearly *not very popular*, so it's unlikely people here will know anything useful about it in particular.

Comment: It's not obvious that this library is compatible with PEP-484-style type hints, which means its use of function annotations is deprecated by PEP 563. (I'm refer to `[x, y]` to mean `Union[x, y]`. Such syntax doesn't *conflict* with anything in PEP 484, but neither is it supported.)

Comment: Yes, you have to write the code that does that, or find a library that does it for you.

Comment: If you use a real time linter (Mypy and pyright have integrations with several IDEs), you can get feedback right away and don’t need to rely on runtime failures. If you want runtime failures for whatever reason, I believe that compilation with mypyc will enforce type correctness  at both compile time and runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add a condition, to check the elements provided through the list, and if any of those are not the `type()` you intended, the function `raise` an error. Like this:

```py
# we define the function my_func
def my_func(a:list) -> None:
  
  # then we cast the type() using map() and lambda
  list_types = list(dict.fromkeys(list(map(lambda x: type(x).__name__, a))))

  # we can now check if the list has more than one item (type)
  if len(list_types) > 1: raise TypeError

  # else we should run the below code
  print(a)
```

If we then:

```py
>>> my_func([1,2,3])
>>> [1, 3, 5]
```

Or we cast a list with more than one type:

```py
>>> my_func([1,'a',3])
>>> TypeError
```

#### Brief Explanation

It casts the `map()` for each element on the list and then we use `list(dict.fromkeys(list_check))` to remove duplicates, the we evaluate if there's more than one citizen, it means more than one type, in that case we should `raise:TypeError`.

May not be the most elegant way but it works, not sure if this would suffice. Also it may be worth checking why your code needs these strongly typed lines, since Python is dynamically typed, you can read some concepts like [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Also here is a **one-liner** of the code above:

```py
  if len(list(dict.fromkeys(list(map(lambda x: type(x).__name__, a))))) > 1:raise TypeError
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: why are you using `type(x).__name__`? Why not just `type(x)`. And why create a `list`, why not just use the `dict`?  Although in this case, why not just use a `set`? Also, that `list(map(...))` is unnecessary, you can just use the `map(...)`. So it could just be `dict.fromkeys(map(type, a))`, or just `set(map(type, a))`

Comment: In any case, I don't think this really addresses the OP's question, which is about getting type hints enforced at runtime, I believe, but to do that generically

Comment: Well thanks for the feedback, you are absolutely right, I was not aware of the correct usage of `set()` before, now it seems more clear, and for the `list(map(...))` that's because I wanted to extract the information given when the map wast cast into the objects of the input list, without using `list()` it returns a map object in memory, but your answer is more elegant and efficient, thanks! :)